# How can I use a code result with a variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I can get result with this bat file that I want. However I can't use this result!

```
@echo off
identify -format "%%wx%%h" E:\Image.jpg
```

Result:

```
640x480
```

I tried something like this ...etc, but they don't work:

```
set var=%%wx%%h
echo %var%
```

How should I do this, thank you so much....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd`'s way to get the output of a command is a `for /f` loop. The following should work (untried):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('identify -format "%%wx%%h" E:\Image.jpg') do set "var=%%a"
echo Result=%%a
```

See `for /?` for details about the loop format.

Note: this works best when the command outputs just one line.